# Whether this sentence constitutes the form "the more, the more"

Tags: grammar

Here is a sentence from one of the LSATs:

- People are less likely to think they see something that is not actually present the less they expect to see it.

I was completely confused regarding its grammatical form.
For one thing, its pattern differs from "the more, the more."
And, I can't figure out why there is no comma before "the less they expect to see it."

Could someone explain to me, please?

Comment: It is still a correlative comparative construction, marked by the comparative phrases "less likely to think ..." and "the less". What may be confusing you is the fact that the subordinate clause is at the end of the matrix clause, whereas it usually occurs in front position. The omission of a comma appears to be a slip.

Comment: What was the test asking you to do with this sentence? Were you supposed to write an interpretaion of it or were you supposed to spot an error in its construction? I would be hard put to spot an error I must admit.

Comment: The more [that] people expect to see a shooting star, the more likely they are to see one. ⇔ The less [that] people expect to see a shooting star, the less likely they are to see one. // _Rearranging the second sentence,_ People are less likely to see a shooting star the less they expect to see one. (_No comma in this variant._)

Comment: *I get more agitated the more I think about it. I get less agitated the less I think about it.* Nothing unusual there - the definite article doesn't *have* to appear on both sides of the "equation".